# Insert values into an array with defined dimensions from a loop

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop

Good afternoon, I am trying to store values in the form of an array from different text files using a loop. I need the values obtained from the first iteration to be stored in the first row of the array, the values obtained from the second iteration in the second array and so on... I tried to do this by initially creating an array of zeros and then replacing the zeros with the respective values of each iteration. However at the end of the loop only the values of the last iteration are stored, that is, I have an array of zeros less in the last line. I may be doing something wrong, but I can't decipher it. Can anyone help me? I leave here an extract of the code.

```
nfile = 0
while nfile < 2:
    a = np.loadtxt('day_'+str(nfile)+'.txt', delimiter=",")
    amax = max(abs(a[:,0]))
    bmax = max(abs(a[:,1]))

    X = np.zeros((2, 2))
    X[nfile] = (amax, bmax)

    nfile = nfile + 1

print(X)
```

The output should be:

```
array([[1.0404, 1.53  ],
       [1.4827, 0.73  ]])
```

This is the output I got:

```
array([[0.    , 0.    ],
       [1.4827, 0.73  ]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing np.zeros((2,2)) in the while loop itself, so at every iteration you are creating a new 2D array. Just initialize np.zeros((2,2)) before the loop, and it will work.